# How to change icon of Secondary Toolbaritem Xamarin Forms

Tags: c#, android, visual-studio, xaml, xamarin.forms

I am trying to set a custom icon to a "Secondary" Order *Toolbaritem* on a ContentPage, but the icon is rendered as the 3-dot /dotted-list icon on Android every time (haven't deployed to iOS, no reason to suspect it's any different).

My code is simply

```
<Toolbaritem Order="Secondary"
Icon="img.png"/>
```

I want to keep the drop-down list function of the Toolbaritem.

Answer (score 1):

That 3-dot icon (Kebab menu icon) is a menu icon. `Order="Secondary"` moves toolbar item to secondary surface, on Android that secondary surface is kebab menu. And [microsoft docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/toolbaritem#primary-and-secondary-menus) have this to say about toolbar items on secondary surface:

> Icon behavior in ToolbarItem objects that have their Order property set to Secondary is inconsistent across platforms. Avoid setting the IconImageSource property on items that appear in the secondary menu.

On Android items are placed in kebab menu and icons are not displayed, while on iOS secondary items are placed just below main toolbar and icons are displayed. I'm not sure about UWP, I currently do not have a way to test it. If what you want is consistent look with icons across all platforms you will have to implement your own toolbar.

EDIT: [This](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/3550) Xamarin.Forms git issue asks for exactly that functionality. Issue seems old but it's still open and there's still some activity, so maybe someday it will be possible to add icons to secondary ToolbarItem on android. In the meantime, they suggest a [workaround](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/comment/145957/#Comment_145957) - use primary `ToolbarItem` with "Kebab menu" logo which when clicked toggles `IsVisible` property on custom `ListView` menu positioned with `RelativeLayout` where your menu should be.

Comment: UWP is no longer supported. Items are displayed in a "drop-down" menu and I know the icon is not displayed, that's why I created this thread. There should be a way to implement this without using a custom renderer.

Comment: I don't really care for how it might even look on iOS , I just want it to work on Android first. iOS has some strange behavior

Comment: What do you mean UWP is no longer supported? See [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/get-started/supported-platforms?tabs=windows). Looked through Xamarin.Forms git, there seems to be no way to do what you want out of the box. Even worse, it seems there is no clean way to implement custom ToolbarItem renderer as renderer is not used for ToolbarItem.

Comment: Dude, Microsoft no longer supports windows phone. https://www.pocket-lint.com/phones/news/microsoft/146804-microsoft-windows-phone-support https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://amp.businessinsider.com/microsoft-ending-security-updates-for-windows-phone-december-10-2019-1&ved=2ahUKEwjx-vSY7r3nAhUROs0KHZrSA38QFjAMegQIBxAB&usg=AOvVaw2qSEuHUKtZFbY7TKFkURH2&ampcf=1 https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://fortune.com/2019/01/19/windows-mobile-phone-microsoft/amp/&ved=2ahUKEwjx-vSY7r3nAhUROs0KHZrSA38QFjANegQICRAB&usg=AOvVaw2wO48iQjaCXge75OL0x9HW&ampcf=1

Comment: UWP is still widely used in Windows 10 and IoT

Comment: Yes, I want to make the Android version of my app work though, not argue with you about some completely different platform though.

Comment: Yes, that argument was indeed off-topic. Anyway, [this](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/3550) Xamarin.Forms issue is exactly what you are looking for, but I doesn't look like it will be possible to add icons to secondary ToolbarItem on Android any time soon. In the mean time, you might try their suggested [workaround](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/comment/145957/#Comment_145957). This, however, still requires you to implement your own "drop-down" menu.

Comment: Thank you sir. Sometimes I miss obvious things (especially when I miss coffee in the morning) I will implement rel-Layout and listview elements; you should update your answer with this info.

Comment: Happens to the best of us, especially when deprived of caffeine. Updated my answer with git link and workaround suggestion. It seems that 3 days ago Xamarin team revisited that particular issue, so it's possible that we will have a better solution in a couple of months or so. Anyway, good luck with your app.