# ToolbarItems icon not showing up

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

how to add an icon before the text "Share"?

below code only displays text and not icon. I have added icon into drawable folder

```xml
<ContentPage.ToolbarItems>
    <ToolbarItem Name="Share" Order="Secondary" IconImageSource="icon_share.png" Icon="icon_share.png" Priority="0" />
    <ToolbarItem Name="Delete" Order="Secondary" IconImageSource="icon_delete.png" Icon="icon_delete.png" Priority="1" />
</ContentPage.ToolbarItems>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The icon for  `Secondary Toolbar item`  is hidden by design .

Check the threads :

[How to change icon of Secondary Toolbaritem Xamarin Forms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60097720/how-to-change-icon-of-secondary-toolbaritem-xamarin-forms).
https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/47989/icon-for-toolbaritem-with-order-secondary.

I create the workaround that mentioned in the links, it works fine .

##### Xaml

```
 <ContentPage.ToolbarItems>
        <ToolbarItem Order="Primary" Icon="dots.png" Priority="1" Clicked="ToolbarItem_Clicked" />
    </ContentPage.ToolbarItems>

    <RelativeLayout>
        <ListView x:Name="SecondaryToolbarListView" 
                  VerticalOptions="Start" 
                  HorizontalOptions="Start"
                  WidthRequest="150" IsVisible="False"
                  ItemTapped="SecondaryToolbarListView_ItemTapped"
                  RelativeLayout.XConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent, Property=Width, Factor=1, Constant=-160}">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ViewCell>
                        <StackLayout  Orientation="Horizontal" Spacing="10" Padding="5,5,5,5">
                            <Image HeightRequest="30" HorizontalOptions="Start" VerticalOptions="Center" Source="{Binding ImagePath}" />
                            <Label FontSize="15" VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalOptions="Start" Text="{Binding MenuText}"/>
                        </StackLayout>
                    </ViewCell>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
    </RelativeLayout>
```

##### Code behind

```
    public class ToolbarItemModel
    {
        public string ImagePath { get; set; }
        public string MenuText { get; set; }
    }
```

```
  public Page2()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            var items = new List<ToolbarItemModel>
            {
                new ToolbarItemModel {ImagePath = "dog.png", MenuText = "First Item"},
                new ToolbarItemModel {ImagePath = "dog.png", MenuText = "Second Item"}
            };
            SecondaryToolbarListView.ItemsSource = items;
        }

        private void ToolbarItem_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SecondaryToolbarListView.IsVisible = !SecondaryToolbarListView.IsVisible;
        }

        private void SecondaryToolbarListView_ItemTapped(object sender, ItemTappedEventArgs e)
        {

        }
```

[image]

Comment: this is amazing! i was stuck on this for long timeeee thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

The Images aren't appearing because you have incorrectly added `icon_share.png` and `icon_delete.png` to your project.

Here is [Microsoft's recommendations on how to add images to your Xamarin.Forms project](https://learn.microsoft.com/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/images?WT.mc_id=mobile-0000-bramin#local-images):

> Image files can be added to each application project and referenced from Xamarin.Forms shared code. This method of distributing images is required when images are platform-specific, such as when using different resolutions on different platforms, or slightly different designs.
>
> To use a single image across all apps, the same filename must be used on every platform, and it should be a valid Android resource name (i.e. only lowercase letters, numerals, the underscore, and the period are allowed).
>
> iOS - The preferred way to manage and support images since iOS 9 is to use Asset Catalog Image Sets, which should contain all of the versions of an image that are necessary to support various devices and scale factors for an application. For more information, see Adding Images to an Asset Catalog Image Set.
>
> Android - Place images in the Resources/drawable directory with Build Action: AndroidResource. High- and low-DPI versions of an image can also be supplied (in appropriately named Resources subdirectories such as drawable-ldpi, drawable-hdpi, and drawable-xhdpi).
>
> Universal Windows Platform (UWP) - By default, images should be placed in the application's root directory with Build Action: Content. Alternatively, images can be placed in a different directory which is then specified with a platform-specific. For more information, see Default image directory on Windows.

#### Recommendations

1. Permanently Remove `Icon`; `Icon` was deprecated in favor of `IconImageSource`
2. Temporarily remove `IconImageSource`, replacing it with `Text="Share"` and `Text="Delete"`:

- This will confirm that `ContentPage.ToolbarItems` is working properly and that you have incorrectly added your `png` images to the Xamarin.Forms project

```xml
<ContentPage.ToolbarItems>
    <ToolbarItem Name="Share" Order="Secondary" Text="Share" />
    <ToolbarItem Name="Delete" Order="Secondary" Text="Delete" />
</ContentPage.ToolbarItems>
```

Comment: just some more info, if I change order to `Primary` than icon works fine. but i would like to use secondary